# Using XCom to Load Schema in Airflow with GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have an XCom associated with the Task ID `database_schema` stored in Airflow that is the JSON schema for a dataset `sales_table` that I want to load into BigQuery.

The data for the BigQuery dataset `sales_table` comes from a CSV file `retailcustomer_data.csv` stored in Google Cloud Storage. The operator for loading the data from GCS to BigQuery is as follows:

```
gcs_to_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(task_id = 'gcs_to_bigquery', bucket = bucket, source_objects = ['retailcustomer_data.csv'], destination_project_dataset_table = dataset_table_name, schema_fields = "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='database_schema')}}", write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE', bigquery_conn_id = bq_connection, google_cloud_storage_conn_id = gcs_connection, dag = dag)
```

When the above operator runs as part of the DAG, I am getting the following error message for the `gcs_to_bigquery` operator.  Does anyone know why the XCom associated with Task ID `database_schema` is not being loaded into `schema_fields` of the `gcs_to_bigquery` operator? And how does one fix this issue?

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/city_retail_project/jobs?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableFieldSchema), "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='database_schema')}}"">
```

Answer (score 1):

- The field [`schema_fields`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b07cb439a0464fcdd143684ec5445ee51fb97cca/airflow/operators/gcs_to_bq.py#L159) of `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` is [NOT included in `template_fields`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b07cb439a0464fcdd143684ec5445ee51fb97cca/airflow/operators/gcs_to_bq.py#L148)
- So what you are trying **will NOT work**

...

Citing [gotchas from `Gtoonstra`](https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/gotchas.html)

> Not all parameters in operators are templated, so you cannot use Jinja
>   templates everywhere. The Jinja templates only work for those fields
>   in operators where it’s listed in the template_fields list inside the
>   source file, like:
>
> ```
> template_fields = ('audit_key', 'cycle_dtm')
> ```

---

Possible workarounds

- Use [`schema_object`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/b07cb439a0464fcdd143684ec5445ee51fb97cca/airflow/operators/gcs_to_bq.py#L61) field instead
- Extend the operator and define your custom templated fields / logic