# Airflow XCom to Python Variable

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have a stored XCom `expense_list` that I want to convert into a Python variable 
`expense_variable` (rather than passing it into a templated field).  I tried to set the variable in my DAG, but the following code did not work.

`expense_variable = "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='expense_list')}}"`

How can I convert the stored XCom `expense_list` into a Python variable `expense_variable` in Airflow?  Is there a function or operator  for this?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that JINJA templating is a helpful feature provided by Airflow guys to ease our lives; and it doesn't mean we have to (or that we should use) JINJA templates everywhere, notwithstanding that we really can't.

Once again citing [gotchas from Gtoonstra](https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/gotchas.html) (that you seemed to have missed [in previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933173/3679900))

> Not all parameters in operators are templated, so you cannot use Jinja
>   templates everywhere. The Jinja templates only work for those fields
>   in operators where it’s listed in the template_fields list inside the
>   source file, like:
>
> ```
> template_fields = ('audit_key', 'cycle_dtm')
> ```

---

In this particular case, there is no reason to pull XCOMs via JINJA template. You can simply refer to the docs that show [how you can pull them](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) via [`task_instance` object](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1322) obtained from `context` dict

`expense_variable = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='expense_list')`